# Create numpy array with another array and an indexing array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have an array `y` that is of shape `(m, n)` and an array `indices` that is of shape `(m, n, k)`. Suppose I want to do the following (in Python):

```
x = np.ndarray(shape=(m,n,k))
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        for l in range(k):
            x[i,j,l] = y[indices[i,j,l],j]
```

Is there a way to do this simply using NumPy that doesn't require using `for` loops?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use for loops? You could use generators which use for loops but are more efficient if that’s what you’re looking for.

Comment: I'm just trying to familiarize myself a little more with NumPy. I certainly could use for loops, I just want to know if there's a simple way to write this using NumPy's functions that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NumPy's [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) for a vectorized assignment -

```
x = y[indices, np.arange(n)[:,None]]
```